# Visual Studio 2010: Location drop down when creating a new project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

VS2008 has a really nice feature when creating a new project, it shows you the folder structure:

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7057/2008v.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7057/2008v.png)

However this either is turned off by default in VS2010 or it is completely missing:

[alt text http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/9686/2010q.png](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/9686/2010q.png)

If this feature exists, does anyone know how to turn it on?

Comment: Confirmed, doesn't work here either. It seems that autocomplete is off for that particular textbox.

Comment: This is a logged and known issue. You can upvote it at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552184/missing-the-autocomplete-feature-of-location-in-the-new-project-dialog?wa=wsignin1.0 in case you are interested